# How to run event handler of specific child on event trigger of parent node

Tags: javascript

I have a scenario where in I have parent object with event handler and its direct children with some event handlers. I just want to know if there is a way by which on clicking on parent node I can get event handler of only child2 triggered?

Like how to get o/p as parent and then child2 on alert box here?

Note:- Event propagation type is capturing.

```
########### . HTML . ################
<ul id="parent">
<li id="child1"></li>
<li id="child2"></li>
<li id="child3"></li>
</ul>

################### JS Code ###################
document.getElementById("parent").addEventListener("click", function(){
    alert("Parent");
}, true);

document.getElementById("child1").addEventListener("click", function(){
    alert("Child1");
}, true);

document.getElementById("child2").addEventListener("click", function(){
    alert("Child2");
}, true);

document.getElementById("child3").addEventListener("click", function(){
    alert("Child3");
}, true);
```

Comment: Should both event handlers to be dispatched?

Comment: yes here I want parent and child2 event handlers to be dispatched.

Comment: The `click` handler for `ul` will be dispatched at click on and `li`. Why have you attached event handlers to `#child1` and `#child3` if the event is not expected to be distached?

Comment: Why child2 ?  Does the user click on child2?